# How to use Twitter User Streams

Tags: twitter

I am new in Twitter API. I have a requirement like I have to pull the information of an authenticated twitter user to know the number of followers. I can do this using REST API but I have a problem here. So I have taken the way to use **Twitter User Streams**.

I am not able to integrate this functionality in the site. I am using **twitter console**( https://dev.twitter.com/console ). But there I am not able to get any kind of result, it actually hangs/shows gateway timeout. And that's for I am not able to configure that how to write the code for this or how to use this in site. I am not passing any kind of parameters.

So, any body can please help in this would be very grateful( a clean sample code for this or any link where to get the good documentation ). I have already checked with twitter dev documentations.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I guess the console hangs because the it is not designed for streams. While the userstream preamble does give you a list of followers it really is overkill. BTW: the "followers_count" is available in https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show (so you don't even have to page)

Comment: PS: this is not a give me code for X site. People will be helpful if you explain where you started and hit problems.